# Starting unity animation from n time ,not from the start

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to ask if it is possible to trigger an animation in unity not from the start ,but from n time in the animation .If the animation lets say 2 second ,is it possible to start the animation sequence after 1 second .

Thanks