# How can I swap out a unity animation for another while keeping the same duration into the animation?

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation

I've seen this question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59512064/starting-unity-animation-from-n-time-not-from-the-start) but it was never answered, and mines a bit different.

As an example: lets say I'm making a character that's constantly on a looping animation, and I have a button that you can hold down to make the character wear sunglasses, the sunglasses are kept on a separate animation of the same framerate and frame count. How can I use the button to switch them but start the new animation on the same frame as the last?

Edit: I've found a function for animators called PlayInFixedTime() [this is the documentation for it](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animator.PlayInFixedTime.html), I don't know what it does but it mentions a "time offset" so it could be what I'm looking for, but I have no clue.

Comment: With Animator, you can get the AnimatorStateInfo. It contains the normalizedTime indicating how much of this animation so you can swap and set new animation to start at the value.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you can solve this in 2 ways:

- Animation Events: via script you are able to select the end of an animation even if it is looping
- Wrap mode: there is an example here (https://answers.unity.com/questions/37080/stopping-an-animation-from-looping-at-the-end.html) but basically you are able to play an animation in Queue after the end of the previous. You can do it with a simple function so you are able to reuse it many times